Template alias with `const char*`
I want to alias/specialize a template that take a const char* as template parameter:
#include <iostream>

template<float v, const char* unit>
struct Displayer {
    void display() const {
        std::cout << v << ' ' << unit << '\n';
    }
};

template<float v>
using MetricDisplayer = Displayer<v, "m">;

int main()
{
    MetricDisplayer<2.5> height;
    height.display();
    return 0;
}

However this gives the error:

<source>:11:41: error: '"m"' is not a valid template argument for type 'const char*' because string literals can never be used in this context`

Mmh... What context, the alias? Can I do a specialization then?
template<float v>
struct MetricDisplayer : public Displayer<v, "m">;

Nope... Same error message:

<source>:11:49: error: '"m"' is not a valid template argument for type 'const char*' because string literals can never be used in this context

So, here was my question: how can I have a reasonably elegant symbol that will instantiate Displayer with a specific string literal?
EDIT: I didn't notice, but this doesn't work at all either!
#include <iostream>

template<float v, const char* unit>
struct Displayer {
    void display() const {
        std::cout << v << ' ' << unit << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    Displayer<2.5f, "m"> height;
    height.display();
    return 0;
}

So, my new question is... How to properly create a template on a non-changing string value?

const char *c1 = "m"; const char *c2 = "m"; there is no requirement that the two pointers be equal. There can be two "m"s. So, if allowed, Displayer<v, "m"> and Displayer<v, "m"> could be two different types. Or they could be the same type.

Maybe you could use types constexpr constructible and convertible to strings?

I would do it like this:
#include <iostream>

// helper to create a string you can use as template parameter
template <std::size_t N>
struct template_string
{
    constexpr template_string(const char (&string)[N]) 
    {
        for(std::size_t n{ 0ul }; n < N; ++n)
            m_string[n] = string[n];
    }

    constexpr std::string_view sv() const noexcept
    {
        return std::string_view{m_string,N};
    }

   
    char m_string[N]{};
};

template<typename template_string unit>
struct Displayer 
{
    static void display(float value) 
    {
        std::cout << value << ' ' << unit.sv() << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    Displayer<"Volt">::display(1.0);
}

